# How chrome.topSites extension API calculate most visited URLs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

The [Chrome Extension API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/topSites) for `topSites` is not informative about how Chrome calculates a "topSite." Even with a clean profile, it's unknown how the mechanism work.

I'm looking for ways to predict whether or not a given site match the criteria to be considered a "top site."

I also tried looking at https://cs.chromium.org as Chromium also has this API built-in, but no luck finding relevant info.

Comment: It's simply a list of sites from history sorted by the number of visits - [source](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/top_sites/top_sites_api.cc).

Comment: thanks but I guess I'm looking to predict when a site from history will populate top sites grid. like minimum number of visits and minimum time spend

Comment: Such event is not exposed to extensions. To see the internal logic we can follow the invocation paths on https://cs.chromium.org and arrive at two implementations of `ProvideTopSites` function, one based on Site Engagement, another is History-based that I mentioned above. Skimming through the references I see both are invoked when a new tab is opened or a URL is deleted from history or a sync is performed.

Comment: thanks again for checking but I guess I'm looking for the algorithm that determines when a website from history is eligible to be a top site

Comment: Uhm? The URLs are grouped as domains, sorted, and the first ones are automatically shown.